# Have I misunderstood the scope of this default argument shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-ptr, libstdc++, default-arguments

Take a look at this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using Foo = int;
using FooPtr = std::shared_ptr<Foo>;

FooPtr makeFoo()
{
    FooPtr f{
        new Foo(),
        [](Foo* ptr) {
            delete ptr;

            std::cerr << "!\n";
        }
    };

    return f;
}

void bar(FooPtr p = {})
{
    p = makeFoo();
}

int main()
{
    bar();
}

// Expected output: '!'
// Failure case: no output (deleter not invoked?)
```

I expected the `shared_ptr` deleter to be called when `bar()` returns, and on my 64-bit CentOS 7 system using GCC 4.8.5, it does.

However, on my 32-bit CentOS 6 system using GCC 4.8.2 under devtoolset-2 (also I *think* under `gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.10_linux`, my Raspberry Pi toolchain), it doesn't.

Looking at the code, and given C++11's experimental nature in 4.8, this smells like a compiler bug to me. But I could also be falling into a UB trap somewhere (or just generally misunderstanding how this stuff ought to work).

Who's at fault? And how should I fix it?

---

#### Works on

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC)
```

#### Fails on

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr --mandir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/share/man --infodir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-plugin --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-20140120/obj-i686-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-20140120/obj-i686-redhat-linux/cloog-install --with-mpc=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-20140120/obj-i686-redhat-linux/mpc-install --with-tune=generic --with-arch=i686 --build=i686-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15) (GCC)
```

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with the default argument, and not just with the copy-capture?

Comment: I have been looking through libstdc++'s Bugzilla and will continue to do so but meh

Comment: @KerrekSB: Good question. The `=` is not necessary in this MCVE. I have reproduced again without and will update the question. (tl;dr: yes)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit might change the subject and tags as well :)

Comment: Also `void bar() { auto p = makeFoo(); }` behaves

Comment: What do you mean 'behaves'? As differentiated from what?

Comment: @SergeyA: It produces the expected output. This is why I believe the default argument is where my confusion (or a libstdc++ bug) lies.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::make_shared`??

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Can `std::make_shared` accept a deleter?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - whoops, good point.

Comment: Do you still want an answer that tells you the lifetime of the parameters or would you just like the section in the standard?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Depends how much rep you want ;)

Comment: `void bar(FooPtr p) {} void bar() { auto p = makeFoo(); bar(p); } int main() { bar(); }` yields the expected output. Guess that's my fix/workaround

Comment: What's the point of an argument that you immediately overwrite?

Comment: @Barmar: It's an MCVE; in reality the argument is only conditionally assigned-to, but that facet is not required to reproduce the observed problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sometimes a CVE can be too M. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nathan has shown, my assumptions about the pointer's lifetime were standard-correct.

That the deleter isn't being invoked does appear to be a GCC or libstdc++ bug, possibly [bug 60367](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60367#c4) given that the linked comment solves it, the symptoms seem similarish and it was fixed before GCC 4.8.5.

Replacing `= {}` with `= FooPtr{}` appears to be a viable workaround.

---

Note well, there is also [a regression in 7.2 and some older "8.0" trunk builds](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82560) that may cause bad behaviour in similar circumstances (thanks [Arne Vogel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4083309/arne-vogel)!).

Comment: There is also a [regression in 7.2 and 8.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82560) that may cause bad behavior in some newer compiler versions.

Comment: @ArneVogel: Oh lordy! Well at least I don't have to worry about such newfangled versions ^_^

Comment: I think you're right that it's bug 60367 (that's the one I thought of as soon as I saw OP's post). GCC 4.8.3 gives the right answer, so that lines up with it being that bug too.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Great, thanks for confirming (fsvo "confirm")

Answer (score 5):

The destructor should be called either when `bar` returns or and the end of the full expression in which `bar` is called.

If we look at [expr.call]/4 (C++17 draft) we have

> When a function is called, each parameter (11.3.5) shall be initialized (11.6, 15.8, 15.1) with its corresponding argument.[...]It is implementation-defined whether the lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns or at the end of the enclosing full-expression.[...]

So `p` should be initialized to a null `FooPtr` at the start of the function, move assigned the return of `MakeFoo`, and then finally destroyed (in turn calling the deleter) at the end of `bar` or after `bar` returns in `main`.

Comment: Okay yeah, or in C++11 the very similar _"The lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns. The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the calling function"_. I'm happy to conclude that this is a GCC bug then but have still not been able to find a bug # to reference :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Out of curiosity, on the broken build, if you do `std::get_deleter(p)` after `p = makeFoo();` does it return `nullptr`?

Comment: It doesn't even compile and I can't work out why. Oh apparently I need to give it the Deleter's type hang on

Comment: Yes, it seems to be `nullptr`

Comment: `std::cerr << std::get_deleter<void(*)(Foo*)>(p) << '\n';` => `0`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Defenitly sounds like a bug where the deleter is not being moved into `p`.

Comment: Yarp. I'd probably be content with working around it and calling it a day, except our main target is the 64-bit CentOS 7 and I'd like to be able to point folks to proof that only the 32-bit targets are affected (if, indeed, that is truly the case). Because it seems a bit odd for the bitness to matter that much, though ultimately it _is_ a different toolchain

Comment: I imagine the real difference is between GCC 4.8.2 and 4.8.5.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Probably.  I'm trying to find a bug report but not having much luck

Comment: Same. Have at least confirmed that CentOS 6 _64-bit_ with GCC 4.8.2 (also devtoolset-2) is affected the same.

Comment: Inspired by https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60367#c4 I changed `= {}` to `= FooPtr{}` and that yields the expected behaviour. Lol.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good find.  Looks like that might be it.  Says it is fixed in 4.8.3 too.

Comment: Yep I think that'll have to do for tonight :) Thanks for your help!